# What happens if loss function is multiplied by a constant?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

What will happen if I multiply a constant to the loss function? I think I will get a larger gradient, right? Is it equal to having a larger learning rate?

Comment: For anybody else ending up here, see this link for a more thorough explanation including normalization: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346299/whats-the-effect-of-scaling-a-loss-function-in-deep-learning

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically - it depends on many things:

1. If you use a classic stochastic / batch / full batch learning with an update rule, where:

   `new_weights = old_weights - learning_rate * gradient`

then due to multiplication commutativity - your claim is true.

2. If you are using any learning method which has an adaptive learning rate (like `ADAM` or `rmsprop`)- then things change a little bit. Then still - your gradients would be affected by multiplication - but a learning rate could not be affected at all. It depends on how new value of a cost function will cooperate with learning algorithm.
3. If you use a learning method in which you have an adaptive gradient but not adaptive learning rate - usually learning rate is affected in a same way like in point 1. (e.g. in `momentum` methods).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I am using an ADAM learning method. I accidentally used total loss of a batch rather than average loss of a batch. But I still had a good result. So I wondered what would be the difference here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right. It is equivalent to changing the learning rate.

Comment: It depends on the way you are solving your minimization problem. With a gradient descent or most iterative algorithm
, yes, it acts like a learning rate. But if one considers the loss function used in decision trees (CART, Gini, ...) I'm not sure it changes anything - depending how you solve them

Comment: @IgorOA You are right. With the tags in the OP, I assume he is talking about gradient descent.